# Find all the values that define an implicit function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

[image]

> Let $h\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
> $h(x,y)=x^2+y^3+xy+x^3+ay$ (where $a\in\mathbb{R}$).
>
> a) Find the values of $a$ for which $h(x,y)=0$ defines $y$ as a
> $\mathscr{C}^1$ implicit function of $x$ in some open neighborhood $U\times V$ of $(0,0).$
>
> b) Find the values of $a$ for which $h(x,y)=0$ defines $x$ as a
> $\mathscr{C}^1$ implicit function of $y$ in some open neighborhood of
> $(0,0)$.
>
> c) Let $f$ be the implicit function $U\to\mathbb{R}$ found in question
> a), and let $F\colon U\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as
> $$F(x,y)=\big(e^{x+y}+x^2-1\mathbin,f(x)+y\cos(x)\big).$$ Show that
> $F$ has an inverse $F^{-1}$, of class $\mathscr{C}^1$, defined in some
> neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Show that $G:=F\circ F+F^{-1}$ is
> differentiable at $(0,0)$, and calculate ${\rm D}G(0,0)$.

Hi everyone, I'm having problems with this exercise, in the first part, what I did was using the implicit function theorem to show that if $a \neq 0$, then y=f(x) and bla, bla. BUT, if $a \neq 0$,
I don't know how to procede, 'cause the differential isn't invertible, and that isn't enough to prove that x doesn't define y as an implicit function.

Same goes for the second one, cause the differential is equal to zero, and I can't use the implicit function theorem.
So, any ideas of how I should proceed?

Comment: You should give the problem statements in English. Many people here don't speak Spanish.

Comment: @MATIAS Based on my memories of Spanish language studied decades ago in high school I've added an English translation to your question. Please check that it's correct. Hint for the first question: we have $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)=x_0+3y_0^2+a$; so $a\neq0$ implies  $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(0,0)\neq0$ and the implicit function theorem applies.

Comment: I think you should check $h(x,f(x))$.

Comment: @jpboucheron Matias is comfortable when the implicit function applies. His question is about the cases when it does not apply.

Comment: @RomulusAugustulus my answer seems to contradict your conclusion, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @tp1 I do not guess what you are suggesting.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah, OK. To me the case $a=0$ was the more easy to prove (question c being more interesting) and I just misunderstood.

Comment: @anne bauval: see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1848176/15519 for explanation.

Comment: sorry, I should've translated to English, but is indeed a perfect translation @jpboucheron and as Anne said, the problem was when I can't apply the theorem, anyway there's already an answer downside that works for me, so thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In question a), for $a=0,$ the equation becomes
$$(y+x)(y^2-xy+x^2+x)=0$$
and has only one $C^1$ solution on a neighborhood of $0:$
$$x\mapsto y=-x$$
because the two other solutions $y$ are real only if $x(4+3x)<0,$ i.e. (for $x$ close to $0$) only if $x<0.$

In question b), for $a=0,$ besides the solution
$$y\mapsto x=-y,$$
there is another one near $(0,0),$ which is also $C^1:$
$$y\mapsto x=\frac{y-1+\sqrt{1-2y-3y^2}}2.$$
But for $a\ne0,$ there is no solution $y\mapsto x$ mapping $0$ to $0$ and differentiable at $0,$ because it would require $x=O(y)$ hence (plugging this into the equation) $ay+O(y^2)=0,$ which is absurd.

Comment: For $a=0$ the graph of the implicit curve is the union of the line $x+y=0$ and the ellipse $x^2+y^2-xy+x=0$, which is tangent to the $(Oy)$ axis.

Comment: Yes, this is what my answer shows ;-) (I had a hard time before discovering this.)